# Remove clicked marker Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to create an interactive map in html/js with Leaflet.

I have a function that creates markers on click :

```
map.on('click', function(e){
    var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
    markers.addLayer(marker)
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup()
    });
```

Now, I want to remove markers when I click on them. However, I cannot find the way to do that. Is there a way to fetch marker id and remove it with a specific method ?

Comment: you need to bind an event to your marker with the `on()` method. `var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).on('click', myFunction());`. In the function you can parse the event, do event.target.remove().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the event method `on()` for your markers and do the logic for removing the marker. You can parse the `event` and do `event.target` to get a reference to your marker and initially use the `remove()` method in order to remove the element from the map.

***Example:***

```
map.on('click', function(e){
    var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).on('click', e => e.target.remove());
    markers.addLayer(marker)
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup()
});
```